# Changing link of <li> without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown that does not have an `id` - I am attempting to change the href value of the `a` nested in the `li` via `JavaScript` or `jQuery`. This is the markup:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="user_info_dropdown" role="menu">  
   <li>
      <a href="myLink.com?id=12431312sdfs2143123"></a> 
   </li> 
</ul>
```

I am wanting to change the link in the anchor tag to `myLink.com?id=12431312sdfs2143123&anotherValue`

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu li a')  should point to your a giving that you do not have that class used somewhere else ?

Comment: Who says you need an ID to select an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that you could target this element.

**Use the Parent**

Since your element is the only element within an list, you could use that from it's target to resolve it :

```
// This should find it and replace it
$('.dropdown-menu ul li:first a').attr('href','...');
```

**Use an Attribute**

If you know exactly what a specific value that needs to be replaced is (i.e. the `href` attribute), you could use jQuery's attribute selectors to find an element with the appropriate contents and update them :

```
// Find a link with a specific URL and update it
$('a[href="myLink.com?id=12431312sdfs2143123"]').attr('href','...');
```

**Broader Strokes**

If you didn't know the exact `href` value that you were targeting, you could apply a more generic approach. That is, replace any `<a>` tags that start with "myLink.com?" and append your querystring value :

```
$('a[href^="myLink.com?"]').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') + '&anotherValue';
});
```

Comment: What would the option look like if all I wanted to do was append the anotherValue text to the end of the url? Knowing that the id is unique and will change with every user? The text of the anchor is fixed though, so is it possible to do it using that?

Comment: You can actually target using the text present in the anchor through jQuery's [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector. For instance, if you knew the text of the `<a>` tag was "Foo", you could simply target it through `$('a:contains("Foo")').attr('href','...')`. Otherwise, the starts with selector similar to the third option could be used.

Comment: So would I just be able to append it to the existing url? Because I will not know the url everytime and nothing needs to be taken off of the url, only added to the end...

Comment: Correct. You could use either the `contains()` or starts with selector (as seen in the third example) to target one or more elements and then simply append your new querystring value to the end via the `attr()` function.